# How is "как нельзя более кстати" different from "как нельзя кстати"?

Tags: значения

> Здоровый критицизм будет **как нельзя более кстати**.
>
> vs: Здоровый критицизм будет  **как нельзя кстати**.

I suppose "как нельзя" by itself already has the meaning of "couldn't be more X", so isn't "более" sort of redundant? Or are these two somehow nuanced?

I wonder if the same goes for: "как нельзя более к месту" vs "как нельзя к месту".

Comment: yeah i too think that более is pleonasm

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Then again, as for "как нельзя лучше", the comparative "лучше" is an integral part of the phrase. So does "кстати" by itself carry a comparative or superlative sense? Is that why "кстати" doesn't mix well with "более"? Come to think of it, I wonder how "как нельзя лучше" compares with "как можно лучше". Is the former for describing the best state/condition something is in, while the latter is  for describing the best manner/way something is done?

Comment: there's a category of adjectives, and probably of adverbs, which inherently denote an absolute quality, so кстати may belong there, you absolutely can say здоровый критицизм будет более кстати(, чем нездоровый), but как нельзя carries superlative meaning and so can't be used alongside более... "как нельзя лучше" VS "как можно лучше" is worth its own question

Answer (score 1):

Оба выражения употреблялись с 1830-х.

Пик употребления "как нельзя более кстати" приходится на 1860-е, потом выражение употреблялось всё реже. С 2010 года употреблений в Корпусе русского языка нет.

"Как нельзя кстати" - сокращённая форма. До примерно 1975 года употреблялась редко. В последней четверти 20 века частота её употребления взлетела. Сокращённая форма вытеснила полную.

Графики:

- [частота "как нельзя более кстати"](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%22%EA%E0%EA%20%ED%E5%EB%FC%E7%FF%20%E1%EE%EB%E5%E5%20%EA%F1%F2%E0%F2%E8%22)
- [частота "как нельзя кстати"](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%22%EA%E0%EA%20%ED%E5%EB%FC%E7%FF%20%EA%F1%F2%E0%F2%E8%22)

PS: то, что в Корпусе нет примеров употреблений полной формы с 2010, не значит, что она совсем вышла из употребления: и выражение (в обеих своих формах) не такое уж частое, и текстов в эти годы относительно немного. Но из двух форм полная встречается гораздо реже, чем сокращённая.

Answer (score 0):

**Как нельзя** is the modern form; **как нельзя более** sounds loquacious and old-fashioned.

That being said, I don't think **более** is technically redundant; **как нельзя более** sounds like it was the original and complete expression, as it admittedly makes a bit more sense — but over time, its first two words came to sufficiently convey the meaning, and **более** was dropped for the sake of brevity, until at some point the full expression began to sound slightly outdated.

As a similar example, I'm reminded of the English word **nonplussed**; given how specific its meaning is, compared to the Latin for "no more" which it incorporates, I'm guessing it's the rump of what was originally a longer Latin expression.